# Pass by reference in function for isset() & empty()

Tags: php, pass-by-reference

Basically I wanted to avoid doing something like this:

```
if((isset($var_1) && !empty($var_1)) || (isset($var_2) && !empty($var_2)) ...) { ....
```

So I created a function to try and solve it:

```
function set($item) {
    return (isset($item) && !empty($item));
}
```

When passing in a variable that isn't set, take for example this:

```
$args = ['derp'];
if(set($args[0]) || $args[1]) {....
```

I get a thrown Notice stating that `"Offset 1` isn't set, but when I change the function to note `$item` by-reference, it drops the PHP Notice:

```
function set(&$item) {
    return (isset($item) && !empty($item));
}
```

### [Here is a demo](http://www.tehplayground.com/#1lZhOun1z)

My question is this - how is this working? Is it because it's referencing the original `$args` array? Am I going insane?

Comment: You can just use `empty()`, it tests whether the variable is set automatically.

Comment: @Barmar I was going to do that but unfortunately for me I'm stuck in a *"You have to code this way when doing this, we aren't giving you any budge"*

Comment: You can pass multiple arguments into `isset()` which might help you to reduce it a bit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a function takes a by-reference argument, warnings about it being undefined are disabled at the time of the call. This is because the function might be used to assign the variable, so it's not an error to pass an undefined variable, or nonexistent index. For instance, suppose you had a function like:

```
function setTo3 (&$arg) {
    $arg = 3;
}

setTo3($array[1]);
```

There's no reason to warn about `$array[1]` not being defined, because `setTo3()` never uses the argument's value.